# WPF stretch fullscreen app to cover whole screen

Tags: c#, wpf, responsive-design, fullscreen

I'm creating simple presentation app. It have to be **fullscreen and UI** have to be responsive eg. it have to scale depending on resolution. Is there a way to strech WPF window to over whole screen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should only need to do a couple things:

1. On your `Window`, set `WindowState="Maximized"`, `ResizeMode="NoResize"`, and `WindowStyle="None"`.
2. Wrap your "slide" presenter in a `Viewbox` with `Stretch="Uniform"`.  That will cause the slides to scale uniformly to fill the window, while maintaining their original aspect ratio.
3. Set the window's background to whichever matte color you want.  If the slide aspect ratio does not match the display aspect ratio, there will be empty regions to the left/right or top/bottom of the slides, and you may want to control the color of those regions.  I recommend `Black`.

Comment: Thank you, you are my livesaver. Also thanks for advices regading slides :)

Answer (score 2):

Setting the [`WindowState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.windowstate(v=vs.110).aspx) to `Maximized` should do the trick.

Something like this:

```
<Window WindowState="Maximized" WindowStyle="None">
    ...
</Window>
```